# Extend sum function for not integers

Tags: generating-functions

Is it possible to extend function [image] for any not integer *y* ?

Comment: What extension? F.i. extend piecewise linear.

Comment: Every function on integers can be extended to all reals in infinitely many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^x\dfrac{1-t^y}{1-t}\,dt$$

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need!